# Why is the Linux wildcard (*) not working for 'mkdir' command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, wildcard

Linux wildcard (*) is not working with some commands like touch, mkdir while my am using * in relative path

While using wildcard (*) in commands, at some places it works but some times it doesn't. I am writing code here please help me to find out my mistake.

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ ls

**mydir**

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ ls my*

list1  list2 **shell_code**

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ **mkdir** my*/abc

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘my*/abc’: No such file or directory

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ **rmdir** my*/shel*

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ **ls my***

list1  list2

**So * works with ls, cd, rmdir but it's not working with mkdir command.**

I am attaching image link also.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind formatting your code using backticks (`\``)? By the way, images of textual content are dispreferred on this site.

Comment: `mkdir` treats the `*` as a literal `*` (and not as a wildcard); this kinda makes sense if you think about how the following should be processed: `mkdir *` ... ????? with `mkdir` (and `touch`) you're *creating* something new so the wildcard would become an infinite match (not allowed), while in the case of `ls`, `cd` and `rmdir` you're referencing something that already exists so the wildcard is a limited match (on what already exists)

Comment: but sir like in my case I have already created **mydir** directory in my current directory (**trainee**). Then I am writing this command `mkdir myd*/new_dir. So why `mkdir` is taking infinite match while I have already created `mydir` directory.

Comment: `my*/abc` is expanded as a single pattern, not as a pattern `my*` followed by some additional text.

Answer (score 3):

Shells like `bash` expand wildcards. Programs like `ls` and `mkdir` don't deal with wildcards at all, they rely on the shell for wildcard expansion.

It is important to understand that a wildcard is expanded to a list of *existing* files.

In your examples, `my*` expands to `mydir` because `mydir` exists, but `my*/abc` does **not** expand to `mydir/abc` because there is no file named `mydir/abc`. So this wildcard is passed to `mkdir` as is. Then `mkdir` tries to make a directory literally named `my*/abc` (wth an asterisk in the name, remember it knows nothing about wildcards) and fails because it requires a directory named `my*` to already exist in order to make a directory under it.

Comment: Sir but If I write this command `ls myd*/newdir`  then it works perfectly. Then why does it expands myd* to mydir ?

Comment: "it works perfectly" what exactly does it do?

Comment: It list out the content of  **newdir** directory which is present inside **mydir** directory

Comment: Again, the shell expands the wildcard _when it matches one or more existing files,_ but not when it doesn't.

Comment: But like as you said it will expend the wildcard if that file or directory exist. So in my case I already created **mydir** directory then why is it not expending while using `mkdir myd*/newdir`

Comment: It expands to `mydir/newdir` because `mydir/newdir` **exists**. It does **not** expand to `mydir/abc` because `mydir/abc` **does not exist**.

Comment: but I have created mydir directory. Please once check this link I have attached a snapshot of the code.   So that you will get idea about what I am asking ? https://ibb.co/JxyhCSc

Comment: You seem to expect that  `my*/abc` should be broken up to `my*` and `abc`, and then `my*` should be expanded to `mydir`, and then the parts should be assembled back to `mydir/abc`. This is not how wildcard matching works. There are no breaking up and assembling back steps. The whole wildcard `my*/abc` must match a whole existing file path like `mydir/abc`.

Comment: Okay I got your point that it will not break up my*/abc whereas it will search for entire path directly. But when I give this type of path to cd, ls , grep, rm etc. commands then it works. So what is the reason of this ?

I have attached one picture associated with it so kindly check it. In this I changed from Home directory to dir2 using same type of wildcard.

https://ibb.co/kGS2XSM

Comment: Do you want me to say this once again? **A wildcard expands to an existing path**. That's all there is to it. You go and check for yourself. Is there a path that matches `my*/abc`? It expands. No such path? Does not expand. I will not be around every time you need to check that, unless you pay me, so you better learn to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The shell performs wildcard expansion on a token level. `my*/nosuchfile` does not match an existing file, so no part of it gets expanded.

You seem to expect `my*` to get expanded to `mydir`, *and it does, in isolation;* but when part of a longer token, the entire token has to match something in order for the shell to perform wildcard expansion.

Comment: but like when I create a new directory inside mydir let's say dir2 then if I write this command

[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ pwd
/home/trainee
`[trainee@esem-linux-jump ~]$ cd my*/dir2`
[trainee@esem-linux-jump **dir2**]$
 
**Now why cd can expand my* to mydir but mkdir or touch command can't do this while mydir existing?**

Comment: Infect when I give this type of path to cd, ls , grep, rm etc. commands then it works. So what is the reason of this ? I have attached one picture associated with it so kindly check it. In this I changed from Home directory to dir2 using same type of wildcard.  https://ibb.co/kGS2XSM

Comment: You seem to be circling closer and closer to the explanation but still not grasping it. `my*/dir2` expands to `mydir/dir2` because it exists. If you also had `myotherdir/dir2` the wildcard would expand to list both of those matches. If no matches exist, the wildcard does not expand.

Answer (score 1):

In `mkdir my*/abc`, the shell tries to expand the wildcard glob `my*/abc` before running `mkdir`, but there is nothing that matches the pattern. Your shell is apparently configured to, instead of reporting an error or replacing it with nothing in such cases, to just pass the string unchanged as a single argument (If using `bash`, that means the `failglob` and `nullglob` options are turned off). And then since the directory `my*` doesn't exist, `mkdir` naturally fails.